# reorder a linked list in place according to a given order

Tags: python, list, linked-list

I am using python to reorder a linked list in place according to a given order. For example, if we have the linked list:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6
```

and we want to order such that the order is now `(4,0,5,2,1,3)`, then the resulting linked list would be:

```
5 -> 1 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4
```

I'm having trouble keeping track of the indices, I seem to keep breaking links when doing the reordering, is there an implementation/pseudocode of a similar problem?

Comment: Since you want an in place reordering, can you also mention how you have implemented the linked list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [4,0,5,2,1,3]
o = []
for v in b:
  o.append(a[v])
```